# Created dev and production push certificate, but only prod appears in keychain

Tags: ios

I created a certificate signing request and used it to generate both a development and production push certificate.
Then I downloaded both of the certificates onto my computer and clicked both of them to install to the keychain.

However within the keychain only production certificate is showing as being associated with the CSR private key, the dev certificate is not, why is this?

Answer (score -3):

You need to generate two separate CSRs, one for development and production each.

Comment: @Undo Ok, I may be wrong then. But would you mind checking Keychain Access and confirming that you don't have the same problem as OP.